# Is upsert in elastic search has concurrency problem?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I know when elasticsearch insert a doc, there is a small duration that client can not find this doc. But my situation is:

When I upsert a doc, which in that time, the doc doesn't exist. So the upsert become insert, and this action success.

Then immediately, another thread/process issue an upsert with this doc, is it possible I overwrite the doc because in that time, the doc can not be found?

Sorry of my poor English...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the situation you described is possible.

One way to get rid of that problem is to use the `refresh=wait_for` [query string parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#docs-update-api-query-params) in order to make sure that the first update/upsert call only returns when the document actually exists and can be found by the second update call.

```
POST index/_update/<id>?refresh=wait_for
{...}
```

However, if two processes call update/upsert at the same time, there's no way to predict which one will win.